# How to sum up values of an array in assembly?

Tags: assembly, low-level

I have been trying to create a program which can sum up all the values of an "array" in assembly, I have done the following:

```
ORG 1000H
TABLE DB DUP(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20)
FIN DB ?
TOTAL DB ?
MAX DB 13
ORG 2000H
MOV AL, 0
MOV CL, OFFSET FIN-OFFSET TABLE
MOV BX, OFFSET TABLE
LOOP: ADD AL, [BX]
INC BX
DEC CL
JNZ LOOP
HLT
END
```

BTW I am using msx88 to compile this code. But I get an error saying that the code 0 has not been recognized.

Any advise?

Comment: Never used MSX88, but it's probably expecting a slightly different constant syntax than you're giving it. `MOV AL, 0` might need to be `MOV AL, $0` or some such; without a user guide for MSX88 it's hard to say.

Comment: I think I figure it out:

Comment: here's what I did:
ORG 1000H
  TABLA dw 5, 2, 10, 4, 5, 0, 4, 8, 1, 9;
  FIN DB ?
ORG 2000H
 MOV AL, 0
 MOV CL, OFFSET FIN-OFFSET TABLA
 MOV BX, OFFSET TABLA
 SUMA: ADD AL, [BX]
 INC BX
 DEC CL
 JNZ SUMA
 HLT
END